# wordpress modal fo each post when clicked read more button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, modal-dialog

I'm trying to display single post content in a modal window in wordpress when "Read More" button is clicked and I got stuck at this step. Modal is being opened, but it shows only a first (latest) post content, not depending on which post you clicked. If I click any post I'm getting only first post content. Pls help me, I want to finish my project.

my index.php

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" role="dialog" class="modal hide fade">

   <!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
 <br>
 <div class="modal-header">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <p><?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); the_content(); endwhile; else: ?>
                        <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
                    <?php endif; ?></p>
                    <p class="posted">Posted at: <br><?php echo get_the_date( 'd-m-Y' ); ?> <?php the_time( 'H:i:s' ); ?></p>
                    <?php comments_template() ?>
  <br><br>
 </div>

</div>
<!-- Modal end -->  
</div>
```

file, where recent posts being displayed with read more buttons:

```html
<div id="posts">

 <div class="post-div"><?php 
        
        $category = get_queried_object_id();
        
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        
        $args = array( 
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'cat' => 2,
                    'paged' => $paged,);
        
        $recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);
        while( $recent_posts->have_posts()) :  
        $recent_posts->the_post(); global $post; ?>
        
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <p><span class="date">Posted at: <br><?php echo get_the_date( 'd-m-Y' ); ?> <?php the_time( 'H:i:s' ); ?></span></p>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?><?php the_post_thumbnail('full') ?><?php endif ?> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed arcu in odio pretium facilisis. Aliquam ut libero id justo lobortis faucibus...</p>
        <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
        
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
 
</div>
```

and javascript:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');  
  
 for ( i=0; i < 50; i++ ) {

  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("read-more")[i];
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to dynamically load the content for the modal. My advice is to start over and use [this article](https://www.codexworld.com/bootstrap-modal-dynamic-content-jquery-ajax-php-mysql/). Near the bottom where it says " Dynamic Bootstrap Modal with Different URL". Examine it and adopt it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

use one addEventListner

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); 
var posts = document.getElementById("posts");
posts.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var button = e.target;
  if(button.classList.contains("read-more"))
    modal.classList.remove("hide");
});
```